# Finding 3D rotation matrix given original and final vector

Tags: vectors, 3d, rotations

I have been trying to solve a graphics course test problem. The problem statement is,

"A camera in 3D is located at point (1, 2, 3) and looks at point (-3, 5, 3). The up direction of the camera is aligned with positive Z axis. Now, you need the camera to be shifted at point (-1, -2, -3) and it will look along direction i+j with up direction -i+j. Determine the corresponding view transformation matrix with appropriate explanation. You do not need to multiply the matrix."

I know I need to make a translation and then a rotation. I am facing problem finding the rotation matrix.

My approach was,
Let's assume, axis of rotation is unit vector, $\mathbf{K}( k_{x} ,k_{y} ,k_{z})$
angle of rotation, $$
using Rodrigues Formula,
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}
k_{x}^{2}( 1-cos\theta ) +cos\theta  & k_{y} k_{x}( 1-cos\theta ) -k_{z} sin\theta  & k_{z} k_{x}( 1-cos\theta ) +k_{y} sin\theta \\
k_{x} k_{y}( 1-cos\theta ) +k_{z} sin\theta  & k_{y}^{2}( 1-cos\theta ) +cos\theta  & k_{z} k_{y}( 1-cos\theta ) -k_{x} sin\theta \\
k_{x} k_{z}( 1-cos\theta ) -k_{y} sin\theta  & k_{y} k_{z}( 1-cos\theta ) +k_{x} sin\theta  & k_{z}^{2}( 1-cos\theta ) +cos\theta 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, I have to solve $6$ equations which I can get from the two original and rotated directions (look and up vector).

Is there any other approach that would help me solve this in an easier way, or this is what I am expected to do?

Comment: Hmm perhaps you can try to divide certain elements of the matrix by other terms ... In the past, I've managed to solve a similar problem like that.

Comment: @MattiP. are you suggesting, using multistep transformation (aligning K with z axis and rotating around z axis) instead of Rodrigues formula? When I tried that, things were looking rather more complex. That's why I switched to Rodrigues

Comment: okay, I have found a relatively easier approach.
instead of finding axis and angle we can construct the whole matrix. 9 unknowns, but we can use matrix inverse and multiplication. consider two given vectors $l$, $u$ and another one $r$ = ($l \times u$).
i've written down the solution here: [https://www.mathcha.io/editor/Xx2gzsqLS21TNelgoJSDdkzDEc3Z0GZPIydMVWX](https://www.mathcha.io/editor/Xx2gzsqLS21TNelgoJSDdkzDEc3Z0GZPIydMVWX)